# Clicking TextView in Android Studio through mobile causes application to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, textview

I am trying to study more on Android Studio and I have been following a tutorial where clicking a TextView will lead the user to another layout. To be more specific, this application first shows the user if they want to log in. If they do not have any login credentials, they can register first. The TextView in the login screen asks the user if they want to register and was supposed to be clickable so it can lead them to the register screen.

To do this, I created a variable register that points to the id of the Textview in the layout. After that, I set up a listener for it. The onClick function within the setOnClickListener function has an intent variable and is passed as an argument in the startActivity function.

Here is the code for the `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private TextView register;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            this.register = findViewById(R.id.tv_main_register);
            this.register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the `AddActivity.java` class. This class is the expected destination of the user once they click the TextView.

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    }
}
```

For the XML layout, I am only using two layouts for this project so far. The first one is the `activity_main.xml`. I will be including the TextView code only which has the id of `tv_main_register`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_main_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="New here? Create an account"
    android:textColor="@color/magenta_light"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_main_login" />
```

I also checked that the `tools:context` of the second layout is set at `.AddActivity`.

I hope I explained it well. I am quite unsure why the application crashes when I click the TextView.

Comment: What is the crash log you are getting?

Comment: Have you checked for the error/crash in the logcat when your app crashes?

Comment: I checked the logcat and it said that it was unable to find explicit activity class.

Comment: Have you declared `AddActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I added it in the manifest just as you said and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

remove `this`.

add context in intent `MainActivity.this`

```
private TextView register;
```

register is defined so no need to write as `this.register` simply write register.

while intent need to write context `MainActivity.this`

```
        register = findViewById(R.id.tv_main_register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = 
                   new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```